# parse a dynamic complex json data into nested java List and Map data structure

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java, I want to write a code which convert my incoming dynamic json file to pojo ,my json and code is as below :

```
{
"dynamic text 1": [{
    "modifyAction": [{
        "VALUE": "test1"
    },
    {
        "VALUE": "test2"
    },
    {
        "VALUE": "test3"
    }]
}],
"dynamic text 2": [{
    "viewAction": [{
        "VALUE": "xyz test 1"
    },
    {
        "VALUE": "xyz test 2"
    }]
},
{
    "modifyAction": [{
        "VALUE": "12981 modify  5"
    },
    {
        "VALUE": "xyz modify 1"
    },
    {
        "VALUE": "xyz modify 2"
    }]
}]
}
```

and here is code snapshot for

```
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(source);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(rootNode.toString());

    final MapType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
    final Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), type);
```

Now i want to iterate this data map so that i can store json in my below pojo

```
public class Dle{

    private String id;
    private Map<String, List<String>> ActionMap;

// getter setter methods here

}
```

where id is "dynamic text1/2" & its corresponding actions "modifyaction"/"viewActions" as map with its values.

Map is getting populated but i am not able to populate List of pojo , for this i need to iterate map but i can iterate it only upto one level.
Note that json is dynamic so keys are not fixed here, they can change e.g. modifyAction can be readAction in future .
please help

Desire output

want to have a List which the id of each Dle should be "dynamic text1", "dynamic text2", ... . Then in each Dle you want to have a Map> which the "modifyAction" is the key and the "test1", "test2" and "test3" are the List elements

Comment: You need to have "dynamic text1", "dynamic text2", ... as the keys in the `ActionMap` right?

Comment: No, "dynamic text1" /"dynamic text2" would be id for Dle and actionMap would have key as "modfiyAction" or "viewAction" & values as its corresponding values below Action.

Comment: e.g. pusedo code --------------                                                    
  List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("test1");
values.add("test2");
values.add("test3");
actionMap.put("modifyAction",values);                                                                                                   ------------------------------------------------------------------                                                         List<Dle> dleList , will contain id as "dynamic text"

Comment: OK, in this pseudo code you ignored the "dynamic text1" as the key and you specified the "modifyAction" as the key for those values: "test1", "test2" and "test3". Which is the correct form?

Comment: i thought of adding "dynamic text1" as id to dle & remaining part in hashmap . if its not that way i am okey with "dynamic text1" as key as you said

Comment: I got it. You want to have a `List<Dle>` which the `id` of each `Dle` should be "dynamic text1", "dynamic text2", ... . Then in each `Dle` you want to have a `Map<String,List<String>>` which the "modifyAction" is the key and the  "test1", "test2" and "test3" are the `List<String>` elements.

Comment: yes yes yes @sTaefi :)

Comment: Your question title and body is somehow vague and I think you should change the question into something like: "parse a dynamic complex json data into nested java List and Map data structure". Then in the body specify the desired output as I digested in the last comment.

Comment: Any idea how can we do this?

Comment: @anika101 Use a custom deserializer and traverse the JSON. Create the objects as you traverse through each node.

Comment: Hi, what's that.?  And please guide I am new to json world

Comment: Can we solve it any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using JsonNode , but is this correct way of doing it?
can it be improved?
Please find answer below :

```
public static void main(String org[]) {


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(new File("C:/temp/test.json"));

        List<DLE> dleList = new ArrayList<DLE>();

        Iterator<String> fieldNames = rootNode.fieldNames();
        while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
            DLE dle = new DLE();
            String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
            JsonNode fieldValue = rootNode.get(fieldName);

            dle.setId(fieldName);

            if (fieldValue.isArray()) {

                dle.setMap(iterateArray(fieldValue));
            }
            dleList.add(dle);

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static Map<String, List<String>> iterateArray(JsonNode arrayNode) {

    Iterator<JsonNode> itr1 = arrayNode.elements();
    Map<String, List<String>> actionMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        JsonNode node = itr1.next();

        if (node.isObject()) {


            Iterator<String> objectNames = node.fieldNames();
            List<String> valueList = null;

            while (objectNames.hasNext()) {
                String objectName = objectNames.next();

                JsonNode objectValue = node.get(objectName);

                if (objectValue.isArray()) {

                    valueList = objectValue.findValuesAsText("VALUE");


                }
                actionMap.put(objectName, valueList);
            }


        }

    }
    return actionMap;
}
```